# Call methods from blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using connection_pool to manage my connections to redis, at the moment I need to use `$redis.with {|conn| conn.set("key", 1)}` to set a key.

How can I do something like

```
redis.set("key", 1)
```

and have the same effect as the above line.

Or at least

```
redis(set("key", 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I see no reason in doing what you’ve asked, here we go:

```
class << redis
  def my_set key, value
    $redis.with { |conn| conn.set key, value }
  end
end
```

and then:

```
redis.my_set 'key', 1
```

For all the methods of interest:

```
class << redis
  %i(set get foo bar).each do |m|
    class_eval <<-CEEOF
      def my_#{m} *args
        $redis.with { |conn| conn.#{m} *args }
      end
    CEEOF
  end
end
```

The list of methods might be automatically yielded from `conn.instance_methods(false)`.

Comment: The idea is not for set only, it should work for any method of conn, the reason for doing this is because I have multiple classes and methods where each methods is doing a call to redis.

Comment: I still don’t get a reason, but please see an update.

Answer (score 1):

According [to the documentation](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool):

> You can use `ConnectionPool::Wrapper` to wrap a single global connection, making it easier to port your connection code over time:
>
> ```
> $redis = ConnectionPool::Wrapper.new(size: 5, timeout: 3) { Redis.connect }
> $redis.sadd('foo', 1)
> $redis.smembers('foo')
> ```
>
> The wrapper uses method_missing to checkout a connection, run the requested method and then immediately check the connection back into the pool. It's not high-performance so you'll want to port your performance sensitive code to use with as soon as possible.

But I suspect it would be just a workaround, the way you are doing it right now seem to be the way the library is designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Two main ways to receive blocks in a method in Ruby:

First is to use the yield keyword like so:

```
def speak
  puts yield
end

speak { "Hello" }
# Hello
#  => nil
```

The other is to prefix the last argument in a method signature with an ampersand which will then create a Proc object from any block passed in.

This object can then be executed with the call method like so:

```
def speak(&block)
  puts block.call
end

speak { "Hello" }
# Hello
#  => nil
```